# javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host locally via netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, iis-7, smtp, netbeans-7

I know that there are many questions on this topic, and I have been searching for an answer for the past 4 months.  Everyone says check host address, port, and firewall.  Well I have done these items, but am still not having any success.

We are running our web application locally using Apache Tomcat 7.0.27 through Netbeans 7.2.1 and are no longer able to connect to the SMTP server to send emails.  When running the application on a virtual machine located on the server, there is no issue connecting.  We have no problem connecting and sending mail using telnet locally with the same parameters.

We have tried looking at the SMTP logs on the server, and were able to access some logs, but can't find any related to the refused connection.  Which SMTP logs would provide more information on this issue?  I tend to think that since the connection is refused it may not even trigger any logging, is this a correct assumption?  We migrated to IIS7 several months ago and were having trouble accessing IIS 6.0 Manager, so I am not sure that they are even set up correctly.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to further troubleshoot the connection?

Thank you in advance, and please let me know if I can provide any further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly this is a problem with a firewall or anti-virus program on your local machine.  If you can connect from that machine using telnet but can't connect from that same machine using a Java application, there's something on that machine preventing Java applications from connecting.

Comment: Yes!!!  Thanks Bill.  We are using Symantic Endpoint Protection which has a setting for Internet Email Auto-Protect.  After turning all virus protection off, I was able to connect to the SMTP server.  I then narrowed it down to the Internet Email Auto-Protect setting.  Hope this helps someone else too!

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same problem while running the Mail sending code and what I found is that the code which I had written recently is using the Java version Jre7. But the older codes run in Jre 6 environment, which works perfectly even now also.

So what I had done is I just change the Jre version of my recent code to Jre 6. After that the code works perfectly without any exception.

So try to change your runtime environment to lower Jre and run the code.